# Javascript Regex replace string between 2 strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out the best way to replace a string between 2 other strings. I believe regex is necessary for this.

Input string:
"http://domainabc.com/dir1/dir2"

Output string:
"http://domainxyz.com/dir1/dir2"

Only the domain will change - not the subdirectories.

Comment: Will the standard [`.replace()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function not work for you in this instance? For instance: `str = str.replace('domainabc.com', 'domainxyz.com');`

Comment: It will not. There will be multiple domains that need to be switched out. Sometimes the domain will be domainabc.com, sometimes domainxyz.com sometimes domain123.com etc.

Comment: Give one or more examples of what you have tried, along with the problems you have encountered, and someone might be able to help you.

Comment: So you want to change one domain for another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're looking to change current domain name without bothering what the domain is. Try this code:

```
var s = "http://domainabc.com/dir1/dir2";
repl = s.replace(/\b(https?:\/\/)[^/]+(.+)$/, "$1domainxyz.com$2");
//=> http://domainxyz.com/dir1/dir2
```

Comment: I've found a workaround solution in the meantime. However, this is the answer I was originally looking for. Thank you!